# Why can't I select current SCN?

Tags: oracle

I can not select the current SCN, with the command that I previously could.

I tried with this command:

```
select current_scn from v$database;
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

select dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number from dual;
ORA-00904: "DBMS_FLASHBACK"."GET_SYSTEM_CHANGE_NUMBER": invalid identifier
```

I get SCN only with this command:

```
select timestamp_to_scn(sysdate) from dual;

TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN(SYSDATE)
-------------------------
           835484
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users by default do not have the privilege to use those objects:

```
[oracle@o7ca1 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Mar 4 20:42:48 2019
Version 19.2.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.2.0.0.0

SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select current_scn from v$database;

CURRENT_SCN
-----------
     564558

SQL> create user u1 identified by u1;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to u1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn u1/u1
Connected.
SQL> select current_scn from v$database;
select current_scn from v$database
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number from dual;
select dbms_flashback.get_system_change_number from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "DBMS_FLASHBACK"."GET_SYSTEM_CHANGE_NUMBER": invalid identifier
```

[DBMS_FLASHBACK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_FLASHBACK.html)

> DBMS_FLASHBACK Security Model
>
> To use the DBMS_FLASHBACK package, you must have the EXECUTE privilege
>   on it.

[About Dynamic Performance Views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/about-dynamic-performance-views.html)

> After installation, only user SYS or anyone with SYSDBA privilege has
>   access to the dynamic performance tables.

We do not know what privileges you had before, that you do not have now.

Ask your DBA to grant you the required privileges.

```
grant read on sys.v_$database to petar;
```

Or:

```
grant execute on dbms_flashback to petar;
```